# TensorFlow: Way to obtain gradients that are internal to a while loop?

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to manipulate the gradients that are internal to a while loop. The actual purpose is to manipulate recurrent-neural-network behavior, but here is a simplified example to get the idea across:

```
t_0 = tf.constant(0)
x_0 = tf.constant(1.0)
size = 3
x_ta = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=size)

def cond(t, x_prev, x_ta):
    return tf.less(t, size)

def body(t, x_prev, x_ta):
    x = 2*x_prev
    x_ta = x_ta.write(t, x)
    return t + 1, x, x_ta

_, _, x_ta = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [t_0, x_0, x_ta])
x = x_ta.pack()

loss = x[size-1]

dloss_dx, = tf.gradients(loss, x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print(sess.run(dloss_dx))
```

In this example, `x[t] = 2*x[t-1]` for all `t`, so we'd *like* `dloss_dx` to be `[4., 2., 1.]`. We instead get `[ 0.  0.  1.]`. I don't think this is a bug, but think it is rather intended behavior: we're actually taking the derivative with respect to the `pack` operation, which `x[2]` doesn't actually depend on.

So: Is there any way to obtain `[4., 2., 1.]` here?

Note: One hacky solution I thought of is to actually compute the gradients within the while loop and then compute a cumulative product (corresponding to the chain rule). But this solution is flawed: it doesn't generalize to vector-valued inputs because `tf.gradients` computes (weighted) sums of derivatives (for reverse autodifferentiation) rather than Jacobians.